# How to properly Sort the values containing Math Constant E?

Tags: sorting

What should I do to reversely sort these values?

```
$sort -r -k 2,2 file1.txt

Pair    FDR
A       7.50515755266e-17
B       4.79431245448e-19
C       3.87331136031e-16
D       3.84586051801e-10
E       3.65371177732e-41
F       3.61621786913e-05
G       3.57733778175e-31
F       2.71393618756e-18
G       0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sort` has a `-g` option that lets you sort scientific-notation numbers like this in numerical order:

```
sort -r -g -k 2,2 file1.txt
```